# Can I show that project scheduling is a type of programming or something similar?

Tags: software-engineering

Project schedules are made of activities, durations associated with each activity, and relationships between activities (SS, SF, FS, FF) with a lag (can be positive, negative, or 0). Let's say I have 3 activities A, B, and C with durations of 2, 3, and 4 respectively and FS relationships between A & C and B & C. A and B will both start on day 1, A will finish at the end of day 2, B will finish at the end of day 3, C will start on day 4, and C will end at the end of day 6. I'm finishing a work term report after working as a scheduler and I'm trying to get it counted as software engineering experience. I vaguely remember one of my professors explaining monoids to me and I feel like I could use that, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What is the definition of *programming* to use, of *type of programming*? Does a "constructive proof" do? I have an inkling that *software engineering experience* includes *formal task definition*, *formal procedure specification*, and at least *systematic test*, if not *proof of correctness*. It may require *procedure specification for machine execution*.

Comment: The biggest problem is showing application of theory. Can I show that I'm applying software engineering theory in scheduling? I do have to go through requirements specification, design, implementation, no testing, and deployment. The whole schedule exists as a system in a software tool, but I don't know if there is a theoretical computer science concept that this could be an example of.